# Predicting if an Application will NOT compile

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compilation

Onlyoffice is supported and compilable on Intel platforms.  Compile [instructions](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/linux/document/compile-source-code.aspx) and system requirements.

This [posting indicates that it is possible to compile for ARM platforms](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DocumentServer/issues/152):

> I have successfully compiled OnlyOffice DocumentServer for ARM (latest
>   GIT clone, on an ODroid XU4 running Debian Jessie) and integrated it
>   with Nextcloud.

**After reading the [instructions](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/linux/document/compile-source-code.aspx) is there any reason to believe that it is NOT possible to compile on for an ARM platform?**  This question is posed **BEFORE** I purchase a Raspberry Pi4 or similar device.

Any cross-compiling best practices or insight into obstacles I would encounter are appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Have you tried contacting the OnlyOffice support? They would be the best ones to give you a good answer.

Comment: Yes, cross-compiling is not a priority and understandably so as their paying customers are X86 shops

Comment: @A.B onlyoffice is substitute for Google Docs: libre-office is a substitute for Microsoft Office.  They are not the same

Comment: oh yes. I know this but somehow completely misread it, sorry.