# Native vs Cross Compile? Porting X86 for ARM Target Platform

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compilation, compiler

[Onlyoffice Document Server](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DocumentServer) is supported and compiled for Intel platforms.  Compile [instructions](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/linux/document/compile-source-code.aspx) and system requirements.

This [posting indicates that it is possible to compile for ARM platforms](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DocumentServer/issues/152):

> I have successfully compiled OnlyOffice DocumentServer for ARM (latest
>   GIT clone, on an ODroid XU4 running Debian Jessie) and integrated it
>   with Nextcloud.

I intend to execute the instructions (compile the application) on the Raspberry Pi 3 to verify the process.  Any cross-compiling best practices or insight into obstacles I would encounter are appreciated.  Thank you

## QUESTION

**Is there any reason not to compile on the target platform and compile on an Intel box?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Predicting if an Application will NOT compile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560344/predicting-if-an-application-will-not-compile)

Comment: This question is almost word for word identical to your last question, posted only 1 hour ago.

Comment: No, my previous question does not address the current question.

Comment: Compiling on the target ought to work if your system has the required software. Note that they specify a 64-bit system. I've seen some software that requires more than 3GB of virtual memory in a single process to compile, and a 32-bit system might not accommodate that.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  Thanks for the insight.  The rPi3 is outfitted with 64-bit 19.10 Ubuntu and will be upgraded to a 4GB-RAM rpi4.

Comment: I don't know what "onlyoffice" is, but if it's something huge like mozilla or webkit, you have all the reason in the world to cross-compile it on a more powerful machine rather than on a puny raspberry pi 3 -- life is short ;-)

Comment: This question reads *so similarly* to your previous question that I can't distinguish them.  If you have a broader question about when to natively compile vs target-compile (any) software, consider saying that here. If it's about cross-compiling this application, then you have already asked that.